# Swap primary and secondary recordset route53 aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-route53

I have 2 aws R53 failover recordsets of A type. 
I am trying to find the best way to swap primary and secondary  recordset in aws route 53 using CLI. My initial thought is to 
1. delete secondary recordset 
2. Update primary recordset to secondary 
3. Create secondary recordset

Is there any better approach or am I in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Use [weighted recordsets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-weighted.html).

To swap DNS records entirely, you would set the weight of one to 0 and the other to 100. If you want to transition deployment slowly, you can set the weights to give proportional responses (so, for example 100 and 100 will direct traffic equally).

Remember that DNS records are cached, so any changes might not take effect immediately. If you expect to do this a lot, set the TTL (time to live) to 60 seconds.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible atleast for now. I am looking for the best way to force a failover by making secondary the primary and run out of the region for a month and then do the reverse.